# Speech To Text Recognizer not found

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm building an app that record the user's voice and then converts it to text. From this post [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253139/speech-to-text-conversion-in-android) I've found the source code [android developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html), I've run the code but the button text reads "RECOGNIZER NOT PRESENT". I think I must be missing some permissions or something becouse earlier I created a Text to Speech converter and it was working fine.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the recognizer functionality is not available on all devices. Make sure you install and update the latest Google Voice Search for Android. I believe it installs the latest recognizer. See http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/ it may be helpful.

As Dante Jiang said in [Converting speech to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402003/converting-speech-to-text), According to [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html), [Google Voice Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch) is what you actually need.

> The Android SDK makes it easy to
>   integrate speech input directly into
>   your own application—just copy and
>   paste from this sample application to
>   get started. Android is an open
>   platform, so your application can
>   potentially make use of any speech
>   recognition service on the device
>   that's registered to receive a
>   RecognizerIntent. Google's Voice
>   Search application, which is
>   pre-installed on many Android devices,
>   responds to a RecognizerIntent by
>   displaying the "Speak now" dialog and
>   streaming audio to Google's
>   servers—the same servers used when a
>   user taps the microphone button on the
>   search widget or the voice-enabled
>   keyboard. (You can check if Voice
>   Search is installed in Settings ➝
>   Applications ➝ Manage applications.)