# RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH not working in new android devices

Tags: voice-recognition

Following is my code for voice recognition, its saying "Recogniser not present" for latest devices and tablets.Please help me how to fix it.

```
public void startMyVoice()
{   
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);   
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, sayClose);   
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

try 
{
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);      
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) 
{                   
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recogniser not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
}

}
```

Comment: Specifically, which devices & tablets are you referring to ?

Comment: Device is Galaxy-S3.                                                 Rom is Slimbean (custom Rom) 4.3. Based on CM 10.

Comment: Same issue with Galaxy-S2 Custom Rom. mostly with Custom ROMs. is there anythin i can do or it is limitation of Custom ROMs

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) documentation:

> When an app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher ... To view other packages, declare your app's need for increased package visibility using the `<queries>` element.

So if you are using `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`, then you will need to declare the same [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH) in `AndroidManifest.xml` outside `<application>` tag like this:

```
<manifest>

    ...

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Otherwise `pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);` will always return an empty list.

Comment: How can I find more apps that support it, to see that it indeed works? I tried to install various, but I don't think the query can find them even with the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

Comment: @androiddeveloper I think it is essentially for the android built-in recognizer. To see it works, try to request speech recognition in Android >=30 with and without declaring it in you manifest file.

Comment: I mean which other apps have this ability? I tried many apps on the Play Store, and I don't think any app there supports this action.

Comment: I didn't come across one as well. Maybe, because most Andoid phones have this built-in.

Answer (score 1):

From: [Speech To Text Recognizer not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253740/speech-to-text-recognizer-not-found)

I am not sure why the recognizer functionality is not available on all devices. Make sure you install and update the latest Google Voice Search for Android. I believe it installs the latest recognizer. See http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/ it may be helpful.

As Dante Jiang said in Converting speech to text, According to this article, Google Voice Search is what you actually need.

> The Android SDK makes it easy to integrate speech input directly into
>   your own application—just copy and paste from this sample application
>   to get started. Android is an open platform, so your application can
>   potentially make use of any speech recognition service on the device
>   that's registered to receive a RecognizerIntent. Google's Voice Search
>   application, which is pre-installed on many Android devices, responds
>   to a RecognizerIntent by displaying the "Speak now" dialog and
>   streaming audio to Google's servers—the same servers used when a user
>   taps the microphone button on the search widget or the voice-enabled
>   keyboard. (You can check if Voice Search is installed in Settings ➝
>   Applications ➝ Manage applications.)

Comment: This `Settings ➝ Applications ➝ Manage applications` path does not exist on Pixel4a running Android 11. The closest I have been able to find is `Apps & notifications > Apps info` and in there, despite recognizer working perfectly, there is no "Google Voice Search application". The closest I have been able to find is `Speech Services by Google`. Is that the direct replacement for `com.google.android.voicesearch`?

Answer (score 0):

Add Below Code In Your AndroidManifest.xml File And It Will Work.

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action
        android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
   </intent>
 </queries>
```

Comment: it's "android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH".  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Comment: The answer by @FaisalKhan is the correct one, works on Android 11, and explains the **why**.