# Speech Recognizer on HTC One M7

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, htc-android

I wrote a speech recognition app using android's built-in speech recognition classes. The following exception shows up in my developer console when the startListening function is called on the speech recognizer object obtained using createSpeechRecognizer(context) function.

SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent
{   act=android.speech.RecognitionService        
    cmp=com.htc.android.voicedictation/.VoiceDictationService 
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Tested working on Nexus 7 & HTC ONE X.

Failed on HTC ONE M7 (4.2.2)

Comment: Show us some code...e.g. how you declared the service in the manifest

Comment: Please take a look at this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253740/speech-to-text-recognizer-not-found?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't declare it in manifest. It's not a class within my app, so I don't need too right? Works on other devices but not HTC ONE

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Thanks for reply. Running latest versions of Google Now and Google Search.

Comment: @Sean87 I don't need to declare it in the manifest because its not a service in my app, is that right?

Comment: SecurityExceptions are 8/10 times a missing manifest entry. Often a missing `<uses-permission />`

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Here's my permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

Comment: Mike, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause of this issue from this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joaomgcd/qcSfL2-SIfk

Solution: Google voice typing must be enabled on a device.

Steps to enable Google voice typing on HTC One device:
http://eguides.sprint.com/support/eguides/htconem8/index.html#htc_one_m8_ug/keyboard_and_input_methods_google_voice_typing.html

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I solved it by Going to Settings-> Language & keyboard -> Voice Input-> Then enable the 'Basic Google recognition', as this radio button was disabled in my same HTC phone.